# Require is not defined react-router-sitemap

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

According to the official documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap) the sitemap-builder.js file should look like this:

```
require('babel-register');

const router = require('./router').default;
const Sitemap = require('../').default;

(
    new Sitemap(router)
        .build('http://my-site.ru')
        .save('./sitemap.xml')
);
```

However, when I run *npm run sitemap* I get an error that *require* is undefined.
I have read that you cant use require in react so I tried import statements ex.

```
import Sitemap from 'react-router-sitemap'
```

But here I get another error that Sitemap is not a constructor

My sitemap-builder.js:

```
import pkg from 'react-router-sitemap';
const { Sitemap } = pkg;

const router = [
    {
        path: '/',
    },
    {
        path: '/pravila',
    },
    {
        path: '/users/:uid',
    },
    {
        path: '/users/:uid/podcats/:pid',
    },
    {
        path: '/post',
    },
    {
        path: '/myprofile',
    }
]

(
    new Sitemap(router)
        .build('https://example.com/')
        .save('./sitemap.xml')
);
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "podcasts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.8.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.5",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-player": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-video-thumbnail": "^0.1.3",
    "reactjs-popup": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "firebase build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sitemap": "babel-node src/sitemap/generator.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.1",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it to destructure the default? `import { default: Sitemap } from 'react-router-sitemap'`

Comment: thanks that have worked, however now I get another error      

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'router' before initialization

Comment: could you update the code or is it exactly the same?

Comment: updated the sitemap-builder.js combined the routes and sitemap in one file and used your suggested changes

Comment: hmm my suggest was `import { default: Sitemap }` but i dont see it

Comment: I was getting a Syntax error like that, but with slight tweaks, I managed to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering I changed this line const { Sitemap } = pkg; with this const { default: Sitemap } = pkg;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `default` of it you can destructure the default property like this:

```
const { default: Sitemap } = pkg
```